# getting data with file_get_content

Tags: php, file-get-contents

my error is this, i have this variables:

```
$request =  "https://xxxxx.xxx.com/2/delivery/request?";
    $request.=  "api_key=".$api_key."&";
    $request.=  "user_id=".$user_id."&";
    $request.=  "deliveery_type=".$delivery_type."&";
    $request.=  "route=E.+Pallares+y+&";
    $request.=  "street_number=110&";
    $request.=  "neighborhood=San Lucas&";
    $request.=  "locality=Distrito&";
    $request.=  "administrative_area_level_1=Distrito&";
    $request.=  "postal_code=04030&";
    $request.=  "country=Mexico&";
    $request.=  "latlng=".$latlng."&";
    $request.=  "destination-route=".$destination_route."&";
    $request.=  "destination-street_number=&";
    $request.=  "destination-neighborhood=&";
    $request.=  "destination-locality=".$destination_locality."&";
    $request.=  "destination-administrative_area_level=".$destination_administrative_area_level."&";
    $request.=  "destination-postal_code=".$destination_postal_code."&";
    $request.=  "destination-country=Mexico&";
    $request.=  "destination-latlng=".$d_latlng."&";
    $request.=  "customer_email=".$customer_email."&";
    $request.=  "customer_phone=".$customer_phone."&";
    $request.=  "notification_email=&";
    $request.=  "notes=".$notes."&";
    $request.=  "dispatch=True";
```

file_get_contents($request);

all this variables are filled automatically, but when i run this with file_get_contents the answer is like that:

```
Warning:  file_get_contents(https://xxxxx.xxx.com/2/delivery/request?api_key=23894thfpoiq10fapo93fmapo&amp;user_id=5744125&amp;deliveery_type=Programado&amp;route=E.+Pallares+y&amp;street_number=110&amp;neighborhood=San Lucas&amp;locality=Distrito+Federal&amp;administrative_area_level_1=Distrito+Federal&amp;postal_code=04030&amp;country=Mexico&amp;latlng=19.346%2C-99.154&amp;destination-route=Pallares+y+Portillo+181+Casa+5%2CParque+San&amp;destination-street_number=&amp;destination-neighborhood=&amp;destination-locality=Coyoacan&amp;destination-administrative_area_level=Distrito+Federal&amp;destination-postal_code=04030&amp;destination-country=Mexico&amp;destination-latlng=19.365%2C-99.1966&amp;customer_email=saul%4099minutos.com&amp;customer_phone=5554&amp;notification_email=&amp;notes=Orden%3A+%231019%2C+Cliente%3A+Ricardo+Torreblanca%2C+Productos%3A+Paquete+Blackmore+ONE+%5Bincluye+1+cafetera+en+comodato+%2B+60+c%C3%A1psulas+mensuales%2C+durante+12+mes in 
/home/public_html/shopify/shipping_test.php on line 1301
```

in my error_log i check and i saw that the url is complete but i don't know why these error

Comment: Yeah, you definitely want to urlencode() those values for each param.  You can't put an unencoded email in a get string (the @ symbol).  (below)

Comment: The warning is a bit odd, it looks like you urlencoded the entire get string...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to want to urlencode the value in each parameter/value segment as in:

```
$request = "https://www.site.tld/path/to/api?param=" . urlencode($value);
```

...etc.

Comment: at the final of code i forget write file_get_contents($request); on this way i have warning when i run my code

Comment: You still need to urlencode each param value separately.  You're sending an email.  We know at least one value is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

You should try sending the gets as stream method;

You can get more info at

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

This will use the built in feature that php has to offer